# How to create MySQL transaction using SLIM framework

Tags: php, mysql, rest, slim

I am using the `Slim` framework to create a `RESTful API`. How can I create a transaction to execute multiple `SQL` statements and/or to be able to rollback some of those statements?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to create and/or roll back transactions using the Slim framework?

Comment: @serakfalcon How to create

Comment: SLIM has nothing to do with databases, it describes only the application interface, the business logic, data access, etc... is up to you... So you can create transactions as usual, `$pdo->beginTransaction()`... You can use [dependency injection](http://docs.slimframework.com/#DI-Overview) and a singleton resource to store the `$pdo` if you frequently need it.

Comment: @Adham - Do you think I should use a SLIM api for a backend? E.g Writing, editing, adding, deleting results for a user based newsfeed?

Answer (score 3):

`SLIM` doesn't come with MySQL attached, so basically you'd do it the normal way, with either PDO or MySQLi, so basically (assuming PDO) you're looking for:

```
$db->beginTransaction();
```

where `$db` is the PDO connection object you're using to use MySQL,
[**see the manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)

However nothing from the transaction is run until you call [`PDO::commit`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php)

```
$db->commit();
```

after which you can call [`PDO::rollBack`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php)

```
$db->rollBack();
```

if anything has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A Slim middleware could be solution to this problem. You can create a slim middleware to open a transaction before your operation, and commit after all. Something like that :

```
class TransactionMiddleware {

  private $db;

  public function __construct(PDO $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
  }

  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next){
    try{
        $this->db->beginTransaction();
        $response = $next($request, $response);
        $this->db->commit();
    } catch(PDOException $pdoe) {
        $db->rollBack();
        throw $pdoe;
    }
    return $response;
  }}
```

Than you can use this class in route action:

```
//$db is a PDO reference 
$tx = new TransactionMiddleware($db);
//action is a method in MyController class to respond to '/' route
$app->post('/', '\MyController:action')->add($tx);
```

I sugest you read the slim middleware docs : https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html .