# Use Transaction in Slim framework

Tags: transactions, slim-3

I use below code to insert or update my data:

```
$app->post('/save_main_operation_info', function ($request) {
    $returning_info = [];
    try {
        $input = $request->getParsedBody();

        $this->logger->info("save_main_operation_info ->");
        $this->logger->info("   operation_id:" . $input['operation_id']);
        $this->logger->info("   register_date:" . $input['register_date']);
        $this->logger->info("   driver_personnel_id:" . $input['driver_personnel_id']);

        $sql   = "INSERT INTO `main_operation`(`operation_id`, `register_date`, `personnel_id`, `implementation_date`) VALUES (:operation_id, :register_date, :personnel_id, :implementation_date)";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue("operation_id", $input['operation_id']);
        $query->bindValue("register_date", $input['register_date']);
        $query->bindValue("personnel_id", $input['driver_personnel_id']);
        $query->bindValue("implementation_date", $input['register_date']);
        $query->execute();

        $returning_info["success"] = true;
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $this->logger->error("save_main_operation_info ->");
        $this->logger->error("    ->" . $exception->getMessage());

        $returning_info["success"]       = false;
        $returning_info["error_message"] = $exception->getMessage();
    }
    return $this->response->withJson($returning_info);
});
```

How can i use transaction when want execute 4 or more query ?
I see [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25483386/how-to-create-mysql-transaction-using-slim-framework) but can not do anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your case PDO is responsible for the database transactions. Here is an example:

```
$app->post('/save_main_operation_info', function ($request) {
    $returning_info = [];

    try {
        $input = $request->getParsedBody();

        // Start a new transaction
        $this->db->beginTransaction();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `main_operation`(`operation_id`, `register_date`, `personnel_id`, `implementation_date`) 
          VALUES (:operation_id, :register_date, :personnel_id, :implementation_date)";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindValue('operation_id', $input['operation_id']);
        $query->bindValue('register_date', $input['register_date']);
        $query->bindValue('personnel_id', $input['driver_personnel_id']);
        $query->bindValue('implementation_date', $input['register_date']);
        $query->execute();

        // execute more queries...
        // ...

        // Commit all transaction changes
        $this->db->commit();

        $returning_info['success'] = true;
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        // Roll back all transaction changes
        $this->db->rollBack();

        $returning_info['success'] = false;
        $returning_info['error_message'] = $exception->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->response->withJson($returning_info);
});
```